# RoR: why does my migration fail when the syntax appears to be correct.

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

```
alex@alex-ThinkPad-T410:~/rails_projects/final$ rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
/home/alex/rails_projects/final/db/migrate/20120813025503_add_price_location_and_product_to_microposts.rb:3: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ';' or '\n'
    add_column :microposts, :price, :text # d...
                ^
/home/alex/rails_projects/final/db/migrate/20120813025503_add_price_location_and_product_to_microposts.rb:3: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting tCOLON2 or '[' or '.'
...add_column :microposts, :price, :text # dont forget to chang...
...                               ^
/home/alex/rails_projects/final/db/migrate/20120813025503_add_price_location_and_product_to_microposts.rb:7: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting $end
```

That is the error. This is the migration  (below)

```
class AddPriceLocationAndProductToMicroposts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def 
    add_column :microposts, :price, :text 
    add_column :microposts, :location, :text
    add_column :microposts, :product, :text
  end
end
```

I wrote it with this in mind http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#changing-migrations sect. 2.2

why does it want semicolons? I am trying to add price, location, product columns to the microposts table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to write method name in front of `def`

i.e. Change `def` to `def change`

```
class AddPriceLocationAndProductToMicroposts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :microposts, :price, :text 
    add_column :microposts, :location, :text
    add_column :microposts, :product, :text
  end
end
```